# Eikonal equation - Snell's law

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am interested in equations of the form $|\nabla d|= F(x)$, where $F(x)$ is piecewise constant and $d(x) = 0$ on $\Gamma_D$, a subset of the boundary. In particular, like in the figure, one can consider $F(x)$ taking two values, delimited by an interface $\Sigma$ (which can be considered smooth).

Snell's law gives a relation between the incidence angles of a ray passing through the interface: $\sin \theta_+/\sin \theta_- = V_+/V_-$. I cannot find any clear references proving that Snell's law holds for the eikonal equation described above. Therefore I arrive at my question:

> 1. Does Snell's law hold across the interface $\Sigma$?

> 2. If the answer to the first question is affirmative, can you indicate references where a proof can be found?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Snell's law holds for any smooth interface, it follows directly from the eikonal equation, see for example section 2.4 of [González-Acuña and Chaparro-Romo  - Stigmatic Optics](https://doi.org/10.1088/978-0-7503-3463-1ch2). I summarize the derivation:

We substitute into the eikonal equation the definition of a ray, being a *unit* vector ${\bf v}$ in the direction of $\nabla d$. Then the eikonal equation $|\nabla d|=F$ can be rewritten in vectorial form as $\nabla d=F{\bf v}$, and hence for any closed contour $C$ one has
$$\oint_C F\,{\bf v}\cdot {\rm d}{\bf l}=\oint_C\nabla d\cdot {\rm d}{\bf l}=0.$$
If you take a contour as in the figure (with tangential unit vector $\hat{\bf t}$ and infinitesimal perpendicular thickness), you arrive at
$$\hat{\bf t}\cdot(V^+{\bf v}_+-V^-{\bf v}_-)=0,$$
which implies Snell's law.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reference and for the intuitive explanation!

Comment: The gradient $\nabla d$ might not be continuous across the interface where the speed changes. Is the contour integral of $\nabla d$ still equal  to zero in this case?

Comment: the component of $\nabla d$ parallel to the interface must be continuous, because $F$ is only discontinuous perpendicularly to the interface, so yes, the contour integral of $\nabla d\cdot{\rm d}{\bf l}$ vanishes.

Comment: "The component of $\nabla d$ parallel to the interface must be continuous" is equivalent to Snell's law. To bring this argument in justifying the contour integral is zero leads to a circular argument.

Comment: circular argument? The continuity statement follows from the eikonal equation, that's all I need. I don't see any logical flaw.

Comment: What I meant is that the continuity of the tangential gradient is exactly Snell's law. If this continuity is obvious, as you say, then there is no need to pass through the contour integration argument.

Comment: First of all, thank you @CarloBeenakker for your great response. Cleared up my doubt as well. Kudos.

Regarding the continuity requirement on the tangential line t in $V^{+}$ and $V^{-}$, by construction of the problem, the gradient of d is constant and it equals $V^{+}=F$ or $V^{-}=F$ depending on whether it is outside or inside.

For the perpendicular part, the line integration can still be performed because F is finite everywhere despite the discontinuity. You just have to break the line into two for integration. Since the thickness tends to 0, those parts of the line integral vanish.